En phpmyadmin no aparecen mis tablas de mi BD pero sí en las carpetas de xampp donde se guardó
Hay una base de datos que deseo importar, pero al momento de hacerlo me marco que las tablas ya existían, por ende, me marcaba error.
Después de checar me di cuenta que las tablas si estaban guardadas en la carpeta.

Pero al momento de ver mi BD en phpmyadmin no sale ninguna tabla de la cual me marca que existe.

¿a que se podría deber?
